# Webbrowser Control - overtyping does not delete selected text when editing HTML

Tags: winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a hosted  WebBrowser control (Winforms .Net 2.0) used as a simple HTML editor.

Although it works mostly as expected, there is one behavior where it differs from most text editors: **if a piece of text is selected in the WebBrowser and then the user types a normal character, nothing happens**. In most text editors any selected text is replaced by the character typed. This only applies when some text is selected in the WebBrowser control.

Is there a simple way of replicating this **correct** functionality? A property I've set incorrectly?

**Solution (Sort Of)**

This appears to be a bug in earlier versions of the WebBrowser control. Windows 7 has the desired behavior, Windows XP has not. There doesn't appear to be a workaround.

Unfortunately Windows 7 / IE10 has added its own new undesirable functionality. See 
[WebBrowser control not auto-selecting text on double-click after IE 10 install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499652/webbrowser-control-not-auto-selecting-text-on-double-click-after-ie-10-install)

Comment: Hmm, no, that's not a common problem.  [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2868160/17034) certainly doesn't have it.

Comment: The suggested duplciate just answers the "how do I host a webbrowser control" question, not "why does it not work when hosted like that in a sensible way".

Comment: Are you saying that the solution in the linked question isn't sensible?  Then you need to show what your kind of sensible looks like, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is required.

Comment: The behavior "nothing happens" if you select a word and they try and overtype a selection is counter-intuitive. In most editors if you have a word selected and then type a different word in its place the selected word is deleted and replaced by the new word.  Here is the SSCCE. Enter the text "hello world" in the WebBrowser control in design/edit mode. Select the text "world" with the mouse. Type "universe". Nothing happens here.

Comment: I already did.  Works fine.

Comment: I see the misunderstanding. I'm trying to edit the HTML using WebBrowser, your example is editing the content of a textbox inside the HTML. Try using <p>Hello World</p> instead of the textarea. The example doesn't appear to put the WebBrowser into design mode.