# A double click does not mark a word as selected

Tags: c#, winforms, html-editor

We are using the `MSDN.Html.Editor.HtmlEditorControl` in a form. The Problem: A double click does not select the word under the mouse.

[image]

Expected: The word should be selected:

[image]

We could not find any registered double click handler that overrides the default behavior.

Comment: Is that https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WinForms-HTML-Editor-01dbce1a/view/Discussions#content ?

Comment: This may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499652/webbrowser-control-not-auto-selecting-text-on-double-click-after-ie-10-install

Comment: Check this, it may help you https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6382c1cc-2a91-42bb-ab05-1fc6f7becef6/double-click-to-select-word-without-trailing-spaces?forum=outlook